# How to perform operation on last node returned by some function?

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly linked list below. Consider two functions `some_function1` and `some_function2`. They both return a pointer to some node. Now, there is another function `do_something` which either does something `(if some_condition = 1)` or nothing `(if some_condition = 0)`. If `some_condition = 1`, then I want it to do some operation on the **last node returned by either `some_function1`** **or `some_function2`**, whichever was last called by the main function. How to achieve this? Thanks

EDIT: What I really want to do is delete the last node that was returned by some_function1 or some_function2.

```
typedef struct Node {

    int item; 
    struct Node *next; 
    struct Node *prev; 

} Node;

typedef struct List {

    Node *current_node;  

} List;



int some_condition = 0; 



int some_function1(List L){
    if (something){
        //do stuff
        some_condition = 1; 
    }
    else{
        //do stuff
        some_condition = 0; 
    }

    return *pointer to some node
}

int some_function2(List L){
    if(something){
        //do stuff
        some_condition = 1;
    }
    else{
        //do stuff
        some_condition = 0; 
    }

    return *pointer to some node 
}

//returns 1 or 0 based on success
int do_something(List L){
    if(some_condition == 1){
        //HERE, I WANT TO DO SOMETHING ON THE NODE THAT WAS LAST RETURNED BY EITHER some_function1 OR some_function2 
        return 1; 

    }
    else{
        return 0; 
    }
    some_condition = 0; 
}
```

Comment: I guess you could store the pointer to the node `L` as a global and then everytime you finish `some_function1()` or `some_function2()` you can update it

Comment: This isn't really answerable from the information given.  If all three routines are called by the same function, I would store a pointer to the most recently returned node and pass it in as a parameter to do_something().  If these really are three wholly separate and unrelated routines, it smells of bad design to me.  Having one routine know what two other unrelated routines are doing is going to be fragile and difficult to scale and maintain.

Comment: Hi @Jabberwock, what I really want to do is delete the last node that was returned by some_function1 or some_function2.

Comment: @novice - why not add `typedef struct List { ...; Node *last_returned; } List;` and update `L->last_returned;` from within each `some_funciton1` and `some_funciton2`. (**note:** this presumes you will pass `List *L` as the parameter to each function -- which you should be doing anyway...)

Comment: It's feeling more and more like do_something ought to take the node to be deleted as a parameter.  My guess is that some function has gathered information from various sources (func1 and func2) and has decided to act on one of them by calling do_something(), which will take all the required action and then delete the node.  If this is correct, it should definitely be receiving the node as a parameter--the less it knows about what is going on, the fewer bugs and the more portability it will have.  I'd also consider shifting the responsibility of deleting to the caller, so it does only one thing

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's a great idea, I'll try that, thanks! :)

Comment: @Jabberwock Building upon your idea of receiving the node as parameter, David suggested including a last_returned pointer in the struct, which I can reference from do_something function by L->last_returned

Comment: You can move `int some_condition` inside `List` as well to get rid of the *global* variable, then just set and use `L->some_condition = 0/1`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ah yep, that works too! THanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the `do_something` function perform an action using the **most recently used** node returned by either of the two functions `some_function1` or `some_function2`.

You can achieve this using a `static` pointer with module scope, to cache the one value:

```
static struct Node * MRU_node;

int some_function1(List L){
    if (something){
        //do stuff
        some_condition = 1; 
    }
    else{
        //do stuff
        some_condition = 0; 
    }

    MRU_node = *pointer to some node    // HERE
    return MRU_node;
}
```

Then add code in the `do_something` function to reference this cache:

```
//returns 1 or 0 based on success
int do_something(List L){
    if (some_condition == 1){
        ... MRU_node ... ; // reference the cached pointer
        return 1; 

    }
    else{
        return 0; 
    }
    some_condition = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Austin! Thanks for your answer. I'm not exactly familiar with static pointers. What I really want to do is delete the last node that was returned by some_function1 or some_function2. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: I begin to suspect that you really should be caching the returned pointer at a higher level, and just calling delete on it when you're ready.

Comment: Yep, someone suggested to add a pointer to the returned node within struct List. That worked well! Thanks for your help :)